# experience manager IE issue

Tags: experience-manager

Site edit button does not appear on IE but appears in Google chrome. Is there any issue on IE for XMP?. Is there any "js" or "css" issue in the same?
Using IE 11 which is the recommended browser as per the installation guide.

Comment: Getting any JS errors in the console?

Comment: I got the issue, my site was not added in Local sites.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please add and accept an answer to assist future users searching for similar problems.

Comment: How can I accept my answer? I am not getting an option.

Comment: Hi user918. You have made a comment not an answer. Use the text area below this comment area, next to the text which says "Your Answer". Once you've made your answer, there is a cooling off period once you answer your own question before you can accept. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I got the issue, my site was not added in Local sites. The site on which XPM needs to be on should be added in "Local sites" of the browser as well as there is reference section in installation manual "Configuring your Web browser for Experience Manager" which can help.